# Proper manner of using two separate if conditions

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have two separate IF checks for a list box within a function called `ExportFiles`. If either check fails (listbox is empty, or no listbox items are selected - which I have another function to check) I want the function to end. Currently I have it written like this, but it seems repetitive and too lengthy. If I combined the criteria into an OR with just one IF, then I couldn't specify the error through two different MsgBoxes. Is there another approach to make this code more concise?

```
If MYBOX.ListCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "ListBox is empty"
    ExportFiles = False
    Exit Function             
End If

If Not IsBoxSelected(MYBOX) Then 
    MsgBox "Nothing is selected in ListBox"
    ExportFiles = False
    Exit Function 
End If
```

Comment: true, but then I would still need to repeat the lines `ExportFiles = False` and `Exit Function` in each part of the structure right? And if I just have each if return an error code, and then pass that to something else, I'm sacrificing speed when then second check is performed even though the first check has already failed.

Comment: What about making the `MsgBox` message generic enough to describe both scenarios?  Then just use an `or`.  This question really might not have a "correct" answer, and might be better suited for Stack Exchange code review.

Comment: Would this also sacrifice speed though? Basically, if either check fails, I want the function to be done. Check 1 fails most often so I put it first. If I were to have an OR, then even if check 1 fails, check 2 is still performed unnecessarily, right? Or does OR exit immediately once the first failed criteria is found?

Comment: Right. In that case, you do repeat ExportFiles = False and Exit Function.

Comment: @Marc is it good practice to set a function's value to FALSE at the beginning, and setting it to TRUE at the end of the function, so that if any unforeseen errors occur, it will end up returning FALSE anyway? If so, then I could just define that earlier, and have the Exit Function command repeat only.

Comment: I think in the end the performance gained by aggregating both conditions would be minimal for the rarer instance that only your second condition proves true. The most consideration I would give is the readability of your code. This is also in regards to your TRUE/FALSE question.

Comment: @nbayly Do you know a source that outlines the best practices for VBA in terms of readibility and such? I've wondered what the gold standard is for code organization.

Comment: I'm not an academically trained coder so I don't follow very many conventions. I would say your own common sense is replicable, so just follow it as you are the biggest reader of your own code. Some code you'll have to write some specific way because of real world practicalities (ie. performance) and others as your example can be written many ways with no measurable difference. The only thing I do follow is naming convention for variables and function names (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110264).